# TCP & UDP sockets using the AndroidAsync library

Tags: android, networking, androidasync-koush

I'm looking for an example of how to use the AndroidAsync library to create a simple Socket or DatagramSocket.  The sample in the git repo, the tests, and the examples on the homepage don't seem to cover this use case.  I see the SocketChannelWrapper and DatagramChannelWrapper classes, but they don't seem to have public constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be done using the [`AsyncServer.connectSocket`](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/master/AndroidAsync/src/com/koushikdutta/async/AsyncServer.java#L367) and [`AsyncServer.connectDatagram`](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/master/AndroidAsync/src/com/koushikdutta/async/AsyncServer.java#L434) methods. Additionaly, an [`AsyncSSLSocketWrapper`](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/master/AndroidAsync/src/com/koushikdutta/async/AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java) can be used to implement SSL.